# Uri.getPath() is null

Tags: java, android, uri

I'm trying to auto-rotate pictures from system gallery intent, but ExifInterface can't get the path from picture uri.
It's crashing on this line:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrM5B.png)

Creating gallery intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.choose_image)), 1);
```

onActivityResult:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, Intent I) {
        super.onActivityResult(RequestCode, ResultCode, I);

        if (RequestCode == 1 && ResultCode == RESULT_OK && I != null && I.getData() != null) {
            uri = I.getData();
            try {
                ImageBitmap = handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(Gallery.this, uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                SelectedImage.setImageBitmap(ImageBitmap);
                detectImage();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Rotating:

```
/**
     * This method is responsible for solving the rotation issue if exist. Also scale the images to
     * 1024x1024 resolution
     *
     * @param context       The current context
     * @param selectedImage The Image URI
     * @return Bitmap image results
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Bitmap handleSamplingAndRotationBitmap(Context context, Uri selectedImage)
            throws IOException {
        int MAX_HEIGHT = 1024;
        int MAX_WIDTH = 1024;

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        InputStream imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);
        imageStream.close();

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, MAX_WIDTH, MAX_HEIGHT);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        imageStream = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage);
        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream, null, options);

        img = rotateImageIfRequired(img, selectedImage);
        return img;
    }

    /**
     * Calculate an inSampleSize for use in a {@link BitmapFactory.Options} object when decoding
     * bitmaps using the decode* methods from {@link BitmapFactory}. This implementation calculates
     * the closest inSampleSize that will result in the final decoded bitmap having a width and
     * height equal to or larger than the requested width and height. This implementation does not
     * ensure a power of 2 is returned for inSampleSize which can be faster when decoding but
     * results in a larger bitmap which isn't as useful for caching purposes.
     *
     * @param options   An options object with out* params already populated (run through a decode*
     *                  method with inJustDecodeBounds==true
     * @param reqWidth  The requested width of the resulting bitmap
     * @param reqHeight The requested height of the resulting bitmap
     * @return The value to be used for inSampleSize
     */
    private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                             int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
            final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
            final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

            // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee a final image
            // with both dimensions larger than or equal to the requested height and width.
            inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;

            // This offers some additional logic in case the image has a strange
            // aspect ratio. For example, a panorama may have a much larger
            // width than height. In these cases the total pixels might still
            // end up being too large to fit comfortably in memory, so we should
            // be more aggressive with sample down the image (=larger inSampleSize).

            final float totalPixels = width * height;

            // Anything more than 2x the requested pixels we'll sample down further
            final float totalReqPixelsCap = reqWidth * reqHeight * 2;

            while (totalPixels / (inSampleSize * inSampleSize) > totalReqPixelsCap) {
                inSampleSize++;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }

    /**
     * Rotate an image if required.
     *
     * @param img           The image bitmap
     * @param selectedImage Image URI
     * @return The resulted Bitmap after manipulation
     */
    private static Bitmap rotateImageIfRequired(Bitmap img, Uri selectedImage) throws IOException {

        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(selectedImage.getPath());//HERE IS PROBLEM
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                return rotateImage(img, 90);
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                return rotateImage(img, 180);
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                return rotateImage(img, 270);
            default:
                return img;
        }
    }

    private static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap img, int degree) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(degree);
        Bitmap rotatedImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(img, 0, 0, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        img.recycle();
        return rotatedImg;
    }
```

This rotating was fully copied from another question, where it works. So i don`t know what is wrong. Uri have path inside, but getPath() can not find it...

Comment: Please post the complete crash logs and your code which you are trying.

Comment: A `Uri` is not a file; there is no path that you can use reliably. Instead, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Pass that `InputStream` to [the AndroidX `ExifInterface` constructor that takes an `InputStream`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface#ExifInterface(java.io.InputStream)).